How to catch "invalid crumb" exception from yfinance in Python 3.11.9?
I have an excel list of tickers which I'm running through yfinance to get fundamental analysis data. I get 2 errors:

"keyError" exception because some data like 'forwardPE' is not available for a given symbol
"404 Client Error: Not Found for url:" when opening the URL I get "Invalid Crumb"

I tried to catch the 404 in the first loop and keyError in the 2nd loop... the 404 catch isn't working.
**
My code:**
import requests
import time
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

the_list_include = []

################################################### OPEN THE EXCEL FILE AND COLLECT THE SYMBOLS
df = pd.read_excel('company_list_404.xlsx')
symbols = df['Symbol'].values.tolist()

for count, symbol in enumerate(symbols):
    try:
        stock = yf.Ticker(symbol)
        the_list_include.append(symbol)
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
        continue

for i in the_list_include:
    try:
        stock = yf.Ticker(i)
        PE = stock.info['forwardPE']
    except KeyError:
        print("\n")
        continue

I tried using multiple exceptions in one line in the 2nd loop:
for i in the_list_include:
    try:
        stock = yf.Ticker(i)
        PE = stock.info['forwardPE']
    except (requests.exceptions.HTTPError, KeyError) as e:
        print("\n")
        continue


https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/ABC?modules=financialData%2CquoteType%2CdefaultKeyStatistics%2CassetProfile%2CsummaryDetail&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com&formatted=false&symbol=ABC&crumb=74gwrZgqcIA
example of URL not working above

you could add this link directly in question. And you could add some symbols  instead of pd.read_excel('company_list_404.xlsx')  - so we could simply copy and run it.

I think Ticker can be lazy and it doesn't make connection when you run Ticker() but when you run .info[]. If I add print() in except requests.exceptions.HTTPError: in  first loop then it never gives error.

I think Ticker can be lazy and it doesn't make connection to server when you run Ticker()
but when you run .info[] or other function.
OR maybe different information need to use different urls so it can't get it at once.
.info may need connection with one url,
but other function may need connection with other url,
so it can't make connection when you create Ticker()
This code can confirm it.
It catchs HTTPError even if I put stock = yf.Ticker(symbol) outside try/except
and I keep only info[] inside try/except
symbols = ['ABC', 'AAL', 'IBM']

for count, symbol in enumerate(symbols):
    print('Symbol:', symbol)
    stock = yf.Ticker(symbol)
    try:
        PE = stock.info['forwardPE']
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        print('  HTTPError:', e)
    except KeyError as e:
        print('  KeyError:', e)

So you may have to always use except requests.exceptions.HTTPError to catch this problem. OR put all code in try/except requests.exceptions.HTTPError

Hello, thanks!  The invalid crumb issue is not picked by "except requests.exceptions.HTTPError", it's not that ticker does not trigger it. I need to process a file with multiple items and I'm not able to treat the invalid crumb exception.
